# A simple php Session class, is the layout/design correct?

Tags: php, design-patterns, mvc

Basically I'm writing a simple framework in php in order to learn more. This session class is extremely rudimentary. At this point I'm not even checking ip/user_agent to prevent session hijacking, it's just basic right now. Also, my `_serialize()` and `_unserialize` functions don't actually do anything special, but they might someday... haven't quite worked through that yet.

Before I started working on this mini framework, I had no idea what `static` was for or `get_instance()` as a Singleton pattern could do. It solved some of my original problems, but I get the feeling that I'm overusing it and I'd really like any explanations or ways to know when to work like that.

I justified setting the class up as I did so that I could, from anywhere in the application, simply call something like `Session::set('foo', 'bar);`, but I'm not sure if that is reason enough or if there is a better way to organize all of my classes.

The `Config::get()` simply fetches a configuration by key, it's sort of obvious what it's doing. The `Database:query()` does just what it says and returns an array of arrays, hence the place where I do something like `$result[0]['data'];`

The session configuration looks like so:

```
config['session'] = array(
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'match_ip' => TRUE,
    'match_user_agent' => TRUE,
    'cookie_expire' => time() + 60 * 60, // One hour
    'cookie_path' => '/',
    'expiration' => 60 * 15, // 15 minutes
    'garbage_probability' => 10 // % of the time
);
```

The actual class looks like:

```
class Session {
    private static $_instance;
    private static $_id;
    private static $_data = array();

    private function __construct()
    {
        self::_start();
        self::_garbage_collection();
    }

    private static function _start()
    {
        if (isset($_COOKIE['session']))
        {
            self::$_id = $_COOKIE['session'];
            $statement = 'SELECT * FROM ' . Config::get('session', 'table') . " WHERE id='" . self::$_id . "'";
            $result = Database::query($statement);
            if ( ! $result)
            {
                self::_new_cookie();
            }
            self::$_data = self::_unserialize($result[0]['data']);
        }
        else
        {
            self::_new_cookie();
        }
    }

    private static function _new_cookie()
    {
        self::$_id = self::_get_unique_id();
        $statement = 'INSERT INTO ' . Config::get('session', 'table') . '(id, data, last_activity)' . " VALUES ('" . self::$_id . "', '" . self::_serialize(self::$_data) . "', " . time() . ')';
        Database::query($statement);
        setcookie('session', self::$_id, time() + Config::get('session', 'expiration'));
    }

    private static function _serialize($data)
    {
        return serialize($data);
    }

    private static function _unserialize($data)
    {
        return unserialize($data);
    }

    public static function set($name, $value)
    {
        $data = self::$_data;
        self::$_data[$name] = $value;
        self::_save_data();
    }

    public static function get($name)
    {
        if (isset(self::$_data[$name]))
        {
            return self::$_data[$name];
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public static function destroy()
    {
        $statement = 'DELETE FROM ' . Config::get('session', 'table') . " WHERE id='" . self::$_id . "'";
        Database::query($statement);
        setcookie('session', '', 1);
    }

    private static function _save_data()
    {
        $data = self::_serialize(self::$_data);
        $statement = 'UPDATE ' . Config::get('session', 'table') . " SET data='{$data}', last_activity='" . time() . "' WHERE id='" . self::$_id . "'";
        Database::query($statement);
    }

    private static function _get_unique_id()
    {
        $pool = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
        $unique = FALSE;
        while ( ! $unique)
        {
            $id = '';
            for($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++)
            {
                $id .= $pool[rand(0, strlen($pool) -1)];
            }
            return $id;

            $result = Database::query('SELECT * FROM ' . Config::get('session', 'table') . ' WHERE id=' . $id);
            if($result)
            {
                $unique = FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                $unique = TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

    public static function _garbage_collection()
    {
        $chance = rand(1, 100);
        $probability = Config::get('session', 'garbage_probability');
        if($chance <= $probability)
        {
            // Clean up
            $expiration = time() - Config::get('session', 'expiration');
            $statement = 'DELETE FROM ' . Config::get('session', 'table') . ' WHERE last_activity < ' . $expiration;
            Database::query($statement);
        }
    }

    public static function get_instance()
    {
        if (! self::$_instance)
        {
            self::$_instance = new Session();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}

/* End of file session.php */
```

Comment: Matthew there are numerous problems with the code. You do abuse static, you really need to understand the concept before applying it. Every static member or function you have shouldn't have been a static (except for those that participate in making this a singleton). It'd take a lot of time for a proper review, please read up on static and revise the code so it'd be easier to identify other issues.

Comment: @YannisRizos, right, I agree. That's actually my main question (how/when to use static). The reason I have troubles is because not static functions can't access the static properties and static function can't access not static properties (which makes more sense).

Comment: The how/when to use static is not a good question for Code Review, as it's a conceptual question. You can ask it on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), with a reference to your question here to get better answers.

Comment: You also *really* don't need methods for serialize / unserialize, when PHP already does this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest problem you have is this:

```
self::$_id = $_COOKIE['session'];
$statement = 'SELECT * FROM ' . Config::get('session', 'table') . " WHERE id='" . self::$_id . "'";
```

You are *blindly* trusting user input. This is not only a vector for a [SQL Injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com/), it is a gaping hole.

*Always use parameterized queries.*

Answer (score 2):

Some generic notes:

1, I agree with @Bobby, the code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

2, I'd invert some condition:

```
private static function _start() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['session'])) {
        self::_new_cookie();
        return;
    }

    self::$_id = $_COOKIE['session'];
    $statement = 'SELECT * FROM ' . Config::get('session', 'table') . " WHERE id='" 
        . self::$_id . "'";
    $result = Database::query($statement);
    if ( ! $result)
    {
        self::_new_cookie();
    }
    self::$_data = self::_unserialize($result[0]['data']);
}
```

and extract out some functions:

```
...
    if ($chance <= $probability) {
        doGarbageCollection();
    }
}

function doGarbageCollection() {
    $expiration = time() - Config::get('session', 'expiration');
    $statement = 'DELETE FROM ' . Config::get('session', 'table') 
        . ' WHERE last_activity < ' . $expiration;
    Database::query($statement);
}
```

It makes the code [flatten](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) which is easier to read.

3, In the `_get_unique_id()` function there is a `return` statement in the middle of the `while` loop. The code after this `return` is dead code, it never runs:

```
return $id;

$result = Database::query('SELECT * FROM ' . Config::get('session', 'table') 
    . ' WHERE id=' . $id);
...
```

I think you should remove that `return`.

4, I'd remove the `unique` flag and restructure the while loop:

```
while (true) {
    $id = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++) {
        $id .= $pool[rand(0, strlen($pool) -1)];
    }

    $result = Database::query('SELECT * FROM ' . Config::get('session', 'table') 
        . ' WHERE id=' . $id);
    if (!$result) {
        return $id;
    }
}
```

It's easier to read and does the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should call that a cookie class.  Cookies are stored on the client side, whereas sessions are stored server side.  ([$_COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) vs [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php))

As you thought, static is causing you problems.  The reasons are:

Your methods are now globally accessible procedures.  The benefit of calling them from anywhere is outweighed by the loss of encapsulation that is at the heart of OOP.

The following are virtually equivalent (its only like a namespace with static):

```
class your
{
   public static function func() {}
}

function your_func() {}
```

Last, but **most importantly**, check out articles on dependency injection.  This post lists quite a few links which are worth reading: [Should i remove static function from my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676515/should-i-remove-static-function-from-my-code)